# Error Building AOSP for Ubuntu 15.04 from Master - Build Stopped Subcommand Failed

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source

Whenever I make android, I am failing with the below error approximately 36% into the make. It doesn't matter which platform I am trying to build -- the same error occurs. I've looked almost everywhere, toyed with the .jack file, .jack-settings file, and still can't fix it.

It seems to occur when the jack server is initializing. I've tried to start the server manually, but it fails:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/android$ jack-admin start-server
/home/osboxes/android/out/host/linux-x86/bin/jack-admin: line 108: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/osboxes/android/out/host/linux-x86/bin/jack-admin: line 108: `      echo "Internal unknown error ($2), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log" >&2'
```

Jack-diagnose doesn't appear to be working. I've been running in circles on the forums. Please help!

Output error below:

```
[ 36% 12150/33274] target Strip (mini debug info).../generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/init)
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: out/target/product/generic/symbols/init: no symbols
[ 36% 12259/33274] target Strip (mini debug info)...ic/obj/EXECUTABLES/healthd_intermediates/healthd)
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: out/target/product/generic/symbols/sbin/healthd: no symbols
[ 36% 12261/33274] Ensure Jack server is installed and started
FAILED: /bin/bash -c "(prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin install-server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-launcher.jar prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar  2>&1 || (exit 0) ) && (JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS=\"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+TieredCompilation\" prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin start-server 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update server prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-server-4.8.ALPHA.jar 4.8.ALPHA 2>&1 || exit 0 ) && (prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-2.28.RELEASE.jar 2.28.RELEASE || exit 47; prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-3.36.CANDIDATE.jar 3.36.CANDIDATE || exit 47; prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin update jack prebuilts/sdk/tools/jacks/jack-4.7.BETA.jar 4.7.BETA || exit 47 )"
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: syntax error near unexpected token `('
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: `      echo "Internal unknown error ($2), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log" >&2'
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: syntax error near unexpected token `('
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: `      echo "Internal unknown error ($2), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log" >&2'
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: syntax error near unexpected token `('
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: `      echo "Internal unknown error ($2), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log" >&2'
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: syntax error near unexpected token `('
prebuilts/sdk/tools/jack-admin: line 108: `      echo "Internal unknown error ($2), try 'jack-diagnose' or see Jack server log" >&2'
[ 36% 12264/33274] host Java: conscrypt-host (out...A_LIBRARIES/conscrypt-host_intermediates/classes)
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:142: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Comment: Were you able to bypass the error?